Swap (Memory really?) leak on fresh(ish) install of 24.04
I installed a minimal (GPT/UEFI) version of 24.04 (with a few extras so far) and it appears to have a swap (memory) leak. It is installed with a common /home with my 22.04 version and this does not show this problem. It gradually slows down and when it fails it ends up logging out and it has reset when I log back in. (One time it crashed everything such that Gnome wouldn't run and I had to re-install.)
Note: I am using free to demo the problem which shows memory & swap and its memory that is increasing. (I was confused because my swap is made up of three parts one of which is disk space of the memory size.)
I have a feeling it is caused by something in my profile as I have another version on another machine working fine (I think). I have searched for a cron process but I couldn't find anything. Whatever it is it doesn't manifest itself when I login using my 22.04 OS and with the common /home
My next step will be to create a new login and see if the problem still manifests itself when I login through it. ...later... Yes, with a new profile everything appears fine. Renaming .bashrc to bashrc did not fix it.
The following shows time vs swap usage increase.
    Wed May 29 09:09:08 AM BST 2024
               total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           3.7Gi       1.6Gi       1.2Gi       199Mi       1.3Gi       2.1Gi
Swap:          113Gi        78Mi       113Gi
Wed May 29 09:10:48 AM BST 2024
               total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           3.7Gi       1.8Gi       1.0Gi       195Mi       1.3Gi       1.9Gi
Swap:          113Gi        78Mi       113Gi
Wed May 29 09:12:28 AM BST 2024
               total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           3.7Gi       2.0Gi       857Mi       195Mi       1.3Gi       1.7Gi
Swap:          113Gi        78Mi       113Gi
Wed May 29 09:14:08 AM BST 2024
               total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           3.7Gi       2.2Gi       645Mi       195Mi       1.3Gi       1.5Gi
Swap:          113Gi        78Mi       113Gi
Wed May 29 09:15:48 AM BST 2024
               total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           3.7Gi       2.4Gi       452Mi       197Mi       1.3Gi       1.3Gi
Swap:          113Gi        78Mi       113Gi
Wed May 29 09:17:28 AM BST 2024
               total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           3.7Gi       2.6Gi       259Mi       195Mi       1.3Gi       1.1Gi
Swap:          113Gi        78Mi       113Gi

Most of the additional installs are the following: -

Thunderbird
Firefox - not the 'snap' version but the Mozilla version.
clamtk
gparted
gufw
synaptic
classicmenu -> with a slight modification to    get it to run.
dkms (possibly)

Artur suggested posting the output of the following: -
htop

ps -ax -eo user,pid,pcpu:5,pmem:5,rss:8=R-MEM,vsz:10=V-MEM,tty:6=TTY,stat:5,bsdstart:7,bsdtime:7,args | (read h; echo "$h"; sort -nr -k 4) | head -10 | less -SEX

I struggled with this a bit as the output cannot be easily copied. The second one of these also seems to output reams of what look like PATHS. I will have another go at this later. I have to swap OS when I test & I mustn't stay logged on too long as there is a risk of trashing the OS (see above)
I did a little better with top
5256 davidp    39  19  752860  71320  17836 D  46.5   1.8   0:36.34 tracker-miner-f
   5347 davidp    20   0 2968452 295920  49868 S  14.6   7.6   0:13.07 gjs       
   4672 davidp    20   0 3938724 300648 131788 S   2.0   7.7   0:08.67 gnome-shell
    272 root      20   0   91832  33160  31624 S   0.7   0.9   0:05.19 systemd-journal
   5419 davidp    20   0  559732  58092  46364 S   0.7   1.5   0:01.64 gnome-terminal-
     50 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.3   0.0   0:00.61 kworker/0:1H-kblockd
   3848 root      20   0       0      0      0 I   0.3   0.0   0:00.04 kworker/u4:3-events_unbound
      1 root      20   0   23780  14840   9464 S   0.0   0.4   0:02.54 systemd   
      2 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 kthreadd  
      3 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 pool_workqueue_release

At one point I thought I saw what looked like several++? snap type processes which all looked very similar.

I have two desktop icons that fail out of about 30. I will add one below and then the difference of two similar ones where one fails and one doesn't
[Desktop Entry]
Terminal=false
Type=Application
StartupNotify=true
Icon=org.gnome.Rhythmbox
#Actions=open-RhythmboxCust;
Name[en_GB]=RhythmboxCust.desktop
#[Desktop Action open-RhythmboxCust]
Exec=bash /home/davidp/Rhymb23.sh



davidp@davidp-DT4102:~/Desktop$ diff Lottery1.desktop U22Lottery1.desktop 
2,3c2
< Name=ACTUAL NAME HERE CHANGED 
< Exec=env WINEPREFIX="/media/davidp/Lin011/davidp/.wine32Lottery" wine C:\\\\windows\\\\command\\\\start.exe /Unix /media/davidp/Lin011/davidp/.wine32Lottery/dosdevices/c:/users/Public/Start\\ Menu/Programs/Lottery\\ checker/Lottery1.lnk
---
> Exec=env WINEPREFIX="/media/davidp/Lin01/davidp/.wine32Lottery" wine C:\\\\windows\\\\command\\\\start.exe /Unix /media/davidp/Lin01/davidp/.wine32Lottery/dosdevices/c:/users/Public/Start\ Menu/Programs/Lottery\ checker/Lottery1.lnk
6d4
< Comment=ACTUAL, NAME, HERE CHANGED.
8,9c6

The bad one is the second one beginning U22.
I have changed some text a bit but tried to keep commas etc similar.
Both these icons worked on 22.04

Added this as a Ubuntu Bug #2067802

What does htop or similar utility tell you about memory consumption for running processes? Here's another command you can use to show the 10 most memory  consuming processes: ps -ax -eo user,pid,pcpu:5,pmem:5,rss:8=R-MEM,vsz:10=V-MEM,tty:6=TTY,stat:5,bsdstart:7,bsdtime:7,args | (read h; echo "$h"; sort -nr -k 4) | head -10 | less -SEX Please include in your question.

I'd say the lines gjs and gnome-shell are probably the ones (they both use lots of CPU and memory). GJS is the Gnome Javascript Engine, which runs Gnome plugins, so my guess is that one of your plugins have a memory leak. Try disabling all plugins, and enable one at a time, until you find out which one gives memory problems.


Don't use so much swap. It is unnecessary. Something like 4 GB would be enough. 2. Given you only have 4GB of system memory, switch to Xubuntu instead of using regular Ubuntu (GNOME DE).


A memory leak is a bug. When you have identified the leaking application or extension, please report it properly to the Ubuntu Bug Tracker. AskUbuntu is not the bug tracker, so you have not reported it yet. It's unclear if you are asking for help identifying the leaking application or filing a proper bug report or perhaps something else.

Artur has suggested (from feedback above) the problem is likely to be gnome plugins.
This commands lists my existing extensions. I have 4:
$ gnome-extensions list
ding@rastersoft.com
tiling-assistant@ubuntu.com
ubuntu-appindicators@ubuntu.com
ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com

Next, to fix the problem, I disabled ding@rastersoft.com with
gnome-extensions disable ding@rastersoft.com

It turns out this adds icons to the desktop. I had noticed that my 22.04 icons where missing in 24.04 but I had placed this as a low priority fix just after 24.04 was installed.
I would say that my desktop Icons are non-standard and are mainly associated with some WINDOWS programs which I have running under WINE.

You can also take off all the icons (mv to a new directory) and then add them one-at-a-time. If they all suddenly vanish you have a bad one so take it off and continue with the rest.

A typical amount of swap is 2x physical RAM. You should not need more.
Suggestions:

Create a dedicated swap partition. Mount it in /etc/fstab, and remove the swap file. If you have 4GB of RAM then 8GB of swap should be enough.
Enable swap compression, which should substantially reduce its usage. Add zswap.enabled=1 to the end of the kernel parameters in /etc/default/grub.
Keep the machine scrupulously up to date, in case this is a bug, in which case it should get fixed. I update every day.


Swap partition is old-fashioned and inflexible ,, stay. but with the swap-file, But reduce it to 8 Gb as recommended.
