ubuntu 22.04 can't see desktop icons
As of recently I can no longer see Desktop icons. I think this is the same problem as in Ubuntu 22.04 desktop icons disappeared, but it wasn't answered there. Note that the desktop folder still exists.

Things I've tried:

Looking in settings
Gnome Tweaks
Gnome Extensions

but no luck so far.
EDIT: more details:
The folder ~/Desktop still exists but my desktop is blank
like I just see the wall paper, none of the files / folders in the ~/Desktop folder
Maybe useful to know:
gnome-extensions list output: ubuntu-appindicators@ubuntu.com ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com
And to clarify, I used to see applications and files and folders show up on the Desktop
More things I tried:
gnome-extensions install ding@rastersoft.com
Error opening file /home/alek/dropbox/ding@rastersoft.com: No such file or directory
gnome-extensions enable ding@rastersoft.com
Extension “ding@rastersoft.com” does not exist
sudo apt install gnome-shell-extension-desktop-icons-ng
gnome-shell-extension-desktop-icons-ng is already the newest version (43-2ubuntu1).

which desktop icons are you referring to? please [edit] your question accordingly.

See the answer to this question https://askubuntu.com/questions/1515740/swap-memory-really-leak-on-freshish-install-of-24-04 Although on 24.04 I also saw this on 22.04 a bit later.

@david I looked at the other post and ran
gnome-extensions list
output:
ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com```

You do not seem to have the desktop   icon gnome extension ding@rastersoft.com  installed. Did you remove it? I believe you get this as standard in a 22.04 install.
to show/install/enable/disable it: -
gnome-extensions show/install/enable/disable ding@rastersoft.com

(select as appropriate.)
Enjoy
Note: If you install -> enable it at it doesn't show any icons beware you might get a memory leak so leave it in a disabled state.
To fix this remove all the icons to a temporary directory, enable the extension (see above) and add each icon, one at a time, and if they appear continue and if they all vanish take it off.

gnome-extensions install ding@rastersoft.com    \ 
Error opening file /home/alek/dropbox/ding@rastersoft.com: No such file or directory
gnome-extensions enable ding@rastersoft.com 
Extension “ding@rastersoft.com” does not exist
sudo apt install gnome-shell-extension-desktop-icons-ng       \ 
gnome-shell-extension-desktop-icons-ng is already the newest version (43-2ubuntu1).

I didn't intentionally remove it, but you are correct that it is weird that it is not there

Ding is pre-installed. It can't be manually updated. Updates are provided through normal updates (if at all). You may need to remove the file you installed through the terminal and "re-install" it from the Browser connector in Firefox or Brave.
https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/2087/desktop-icons-ng-ding/  ... You should see desktop icons now... If not, open extension-manager, select Ding settings and make sure it's set up to show icons... I had an issue with Ding and just wanted to disable it, so I did this:
First install dconf editor with: sudo apt-get install dconf-editor. Open your Extensions Manager and find Ding and turn it off/disable it.  Then open the dconf app from your apps menu and go to: org.gnome.desktop.background and change (confirm) show-desktop-icons to true. NOTE: You will need to restart you computer to see changes. Reboot and then right-click on the desktop and you'll see a menu. Choose "customize" and this will open the x-settings "Current Monitor Settings" (mine is Wayland). That is the menu for icons/mounted volumes. Choose your preferred settings and done. Hope this helps.
