Ubuntu 24.04 screen freezes quite often
Facing this issue after I upgraded to Ubuntu 24.04 few months back.
I tried various solutions on this forum as well as on other forums, but got no permanent result.
After recommendation from one of the forum post I installed the disk repair tool and following is the result.
https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/W7NNPypN8p/
I am not an expert in ubuntu or hardware. Mainly working as a developer of php.
So if anyone can guide me whats wrong in the system and how can i correct it ?
Thanks in advance.

possibly a hardware fault ... or graphics driver issue ...  are you using the default graphics driver ?

Yes default graphics driver.
But this laptop i am using for last 5-6 years without any issue. Only after upgrading to 24.04 this issue started that too after few months not immediately

https://askubuntu.com/questions/1515740/swap-memory-really-leak-on-freshish-install-of-24-04 2nd answer in this post was useful and it solved my problem. All my icons are gone from the desktop though.

in effort to help other folks who might get same issue I suggest you give this question of yours an answer detailing how you solved it ... take care

The log file in the pastebin literally gives you the solution. Shut off Legacy boot mode.
    Suggested repair: ______________________________________________________________

The default repair of the Boot-Repair utility would purge   
(in order to fix packages) and reinstall the grub-efi of sda7,  
using the following options:  sda1/boot/efi  
Additional repair would be performed:   
unhide-bootmenu-10s use-standard-efi-file

Blockers in case of suggested repair: __________________________________________

WindowsEFI detected.  
Please disable BIOS-compatibility/CSM/Legacy mode in your UEFI firmware, 
and use this software from a live-CD (or live-USB)   
that is compatible with UEFI booting mode.   
For example, use a live-USB of Boot-Repair-Disk-64bit   
(www.sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair-cd),   
after making sure your BIOS is set up to boot USB in EFI mode. 

Final advice in case of suggested repair: ______________________________________

Please do not forget to make your UEFI firmware boot on the OS now in use - Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS entry (sda1/efi/****/grub****.efi   
(**** will be updated in the final message) file) !
If your computer reboots directly into Windows, try to change the boot order in your UEFI firmware.  
If your UEFI firmware does not allow to change the boot order, change the default boot entry of the Windows bootloader.  
For example you can boot into Windows, then type the following command in an admin command prompt:  
bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\****\grub****.efi (**** will be updated in the final message)  
The boot of your PC is in BIOS-compatibility/CSM/Legacy mode. You may want to retry after changing it to UEFI mode.  


You'd be surprised how often Linux distros just put stuff for you in plain text so you and everyone else can read. I don't 100% know how this makes sense myself since I'm not an expert on anything (I just like to read log files I guess) but if you've got an NVIDIA card this makes perfect sense. Their drivers are very picky and won't work with Legacy boot on

I solved the issue by following solution mentioned in the post
Swap (Memory really?) leak on fresh(ish) install of 24.04.
Artur has suggested (from feedback above) the problem is likely to be gnome plugins.
This commands lists my existing extensions. I have 4:
$ gnome-extensions list
ding@rastersoft.com
tiling-assistant@ubuntu.com
ubuntu-appindicators@ubuntu.com
ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com
Next, to fix the problem, I disabled ding@rastersoft.com with
gnome-extensions disable ding@rastersoft.com
It turns out this adds icons to the desktop and after disabling it my desktop icons were gone. But thats fine with me as I dont use desktop icons much.
But this resolved my problem completely.
