Ubuntu 22.04 Freezes Randomly and Requires Hard Reboot
Here are my system specs:

Ryzen 1700 CPU
GTX 1080
16GB DDR4 RAM
Running Ubuntu 22.04.5
Kernel: 6.8.0-48-generic
Running dual boot with Windows 10

At completely random moments, my computer completely freezes, meaning it becomes completely unresponsive. The keyboard, mouse, display, and sounds completely freeze. This requires me to hold the power button to reboot the computer.
Here is the peculiar part: 
When the system freezes, I hard reset it with the power button. However, every time after rebooting like this, I have to restart the computer a second time, because the system cannot detect any available WiFi connections otherwise. To summarize, this is what I have to do every time the computer freezes:

The system completely freezes
I hold the power button to turn the PC off and then press it to turn it on
The system turns on fine. However, I cannot detect any available WiFi connections.
I restart the computer again (this time I just restart over software by typing reboot in the terminal or clicking restart in the top right toolbar).
The system now works fine, until another freeze occurs, at a random time later.

Has anyone encountered a situation like this? I have looked around online, and nothing seems to fix this issue. Would appreciate any guidance.

I met these kind of situations before. I relize that it because one of my external DAC plug to PC through USB port. After remove that problem never happen. Maybe your wifi device has compatible problem. You can try by unplug it.

Thank you for the response. I doubt that it is my wifi adapter, as I am using a USB one at the moment. I was facing this issue before when I was using a PCIe adapter (with the USB adapter not present). It is very weird, as these issues do not occur when I boot in Windows.

I think Windows always has better support for a wider variety of devices.

A long shot. I had a problem with 24.04 with a memory leak. The symptoms are a gradual slowing down and then a crash. See https://askubuntu.com/questions/1515740/swap-memory-really-leak-on-freshish-install-of-24-04

I replaced my usb wifi adapter with ethernet, and the issue is still present. I am going to replace my peripherals one by one to see if either my keyboard or my mouse is causing the problem.
