24.0.1 becomes unresponsive after a while
A few times I have left my computer on overnight and when I come back to it the screen is black and the system is unresponsive.   Just now it started to get slower and slower while I was using it and the mouse stopped moving. It then recovered and I looked at dmesg. There I saw:
A lot lines like:
[639644.653878] systemd-journald[407]: Under memory pressure, flushing caches. 

then
[661080.310095] snapd invoked oom-killer: gfp_mask=0x140cca(GFP_HIGHUSER_MOVABLE|__GFP_COMP), order=0, oom_score_adj=-900
[661080.310105] CPU: 1 PID: 1492 Comm: snapd Not tainted 6.8.0-48-generic #48-Ubuntu
[661080.310109] Hardware name: CCL Computers Custom PC/A320M-S2H V2-CF, BIOS F51c 07/02/2020
[661080.310111] Call Trace:
[661080.310114]  <TASK>
[661080.310118]  dump_stack_lvl+0x76/0xa0
[661080.310125]  dump_stack+0x10/0x20
[661080.310128]  dump_header+0x47/0x1f0
[661080.310133]  oom_kill_process+0x118/0x280
[661080.310136]  ? srso_return_thunk+0x5/0x5f
[661080.310140]  ? oom_evaluate_task+0x143/0x1e0
[661080.310144]  out_of_memory+0x103/0x350
[661080.310148]  __alloc_pages_may_oom+0x10c/0x1d0
[661080.310155]  __alloc_pages_slowpath.constprop.0+0x420/0x9f0
[661080.310161]  __alloc_pages+0x31f/0x350
[661080.310167]  alloc_pages_mpol+0x91/0x210
[661080.310172]  folio_alloc+0x64/0x120
[661080.310175]  ? filemap_get_entry+0xe5/0x160
[661080.310179]  filemap_alloc_folio+0xf4/0x100
[661080.310184]  __filemap_get_folio+0x14b/0x2f0
[661080.310189]  filemap_fault+0x15c/0x8e0
[661080.310191]  ? __lruvec_stat_mod_folio+0x70/0xc0
[661080.310197]  ? srso_return_thunk+0x5/0x5f
[661080.310199]  ? set_pte_range+0x10b/0x2f0
[661080.310204]  __do_fault+0x3b/0x140
[661080.310208]  do_read_fault+0x133/0x1d0
[661080.310212]  do_fault+0x109/0x350
[661080.310214]  ? srso_return_thunk+0x5/0x5f
[661080.310218]  handle_pte_fault+0x114/0x1d0
[661080.310222]  __handle_mm_fault+0x653/0x790
[661080.310229]  handle_mm_fault+0x18a/0x380
[661080.310233]  do_user_addr_fault+0x169/0x670
[661080.310239]  exc_page_fault+0x83/0x1b0
[661080.310244]  asm_exc_page_fault+0x27/0x30
[661080.310248] RIP: 0033:0x620170b2c340
[661080.310268] Code: Unable to access opcode bytes at 0x620170b2c316.
[661080.310270] RSP: 002b:000000c000807860 EFLAGS: 00010246
[661080.310273] RAX: 0000620171a1a600 RBX: 0000000000000979 RCX: 0000000000000979
[661080.310276] RDX: 0000000000000000 RSI: 0000620171a1a687 RDI: 0000620171a1a687
[661080.310276] RDX: 0000000000000000 RSI: 0000620171a1a687 RDI: 0000620171a1a687
[661080.310278] RBP: 000000c0008078b0 R08: 000000c000807880 R09: 0000620171de4408
[661080.310280] R10: 0000000000000001 R11: 0000620171a1afe0 R12: 000000c000807870
[661080.310282] R13: 0000000000000001 R14: 000000c0005c2c40 R15: 000000c00030e000
[661080.310288]  </TASK>
[661080.310289] Mem-Info:
[661080.310291] active_anon:2553381 inactive_anon:714264 isolated_anon:0
                 active_file:1112 inactive_file:1479 isolated_file:0
                 unevictable:8 dirty:1 writeback:4
                 slab_reclaimable:53597 slab_unreclaimable:111716
                 mapped:3258 shmem:10887 pagetables:27895
                 sec_pagetables:0 bounce:0
                 kernel_misc_reclaimable:0
                 free:35090 free_pcp:1198 free_cma:0

then
[661080.310298] Node 0 active_anon:10216868kB inactive_anon:2853712kB active_file:4448kB inactive_file:5916kB unevictable:32kB isolated(anon):
0kB isolated(file):0kB mapped:13032kB dirty:4kB writeback:16kB shmem:43548kB shmem_thp:0kB shmem_pmdmapped:0kB anon_thp:0kB writeback_tmp:0kB 
kernel_stack:27504kB pagetables:111580kB sec_pagetables:0kB all_unreclaimable? no
[661080.310304] Node 0 DMA free:13324kB boost:0kB min:72kB low:88kB high:104kB reserved_highatomic:0KB active_anon:0kB inactive_anon:0kB activ
e_file:0kB inactive_file:0kB unevictable:0kB writepending:0kB present:15996kB managed:15372kB mlocked:0kB bounce:0kB free_pcp:0kB local_pcp:0k
B free_cma:0kB
[661080.310310] lowmem_reserve[]: 0 1353 13830 13830 13830
[661080.310318] Node 0 DMA32 free:56096kB boost:0kB min:6604kB low:8252kB high:9900kB reserved_highatomic:0KB active_anon:706040kB inactive_anon:628632kB active_file:688kB inactive_file:816kB unevictable:0kB writepending:8kB present:1515676kB managed:1449740kB mlocked:0kB bounce:0kB free_pcp:2204kB local_pcp:772kB free_cma:0kB
[661080.310324] lowmem_reserve[]: 0 0 12477 12477 12477
[661080.310331] Node 0 Normal free:70940kB boost:0kB min:60904kB low:76128kB high:91352kB reserved_highatomic:10240KB active_anon:9510788kB inactive_anon:2225120kB active_file:4248kB inactive_file:4352kB unevictable:32kB writepending:12kB present:13094144kB managed:12783720kB mlocked:32kB bounce:0kB free_pcp:2588kB local_pcp:108kB free_cma:0kB
[661080.310338] lowmem_reserve[]: 0 0 0 0 0
[661080.310344] Node 0 DMA: 1*4kB (U) 1*8kB (U) 0*16kB 0*32kB 0*64kB 0*128kB 0*256kB 0*512kB 1*1024kB (U) 2*2048kB (UM) 2*4096kB (M) = 13324kB
[661080.310365] Node 0 DMA32: 351*4kB (UE) 657*8kB (UME) 498*16kB (UME) 296*32kB (UME) 142*64kB (UME) 71*128kB (UME) 32*256kB (UME) 3*512kB (UE) 0*1024kB 2*2048kB (M) 0*4096kB = 56100kB
[661080.310390] Node 0 Normal: 1255*4kB (UME) 1090*8kB (UME) 1117*16kB (UME) 698*32kB (UME) 177*64kB (UME) 21*128kB (UME) 2*256kB (M) 1*512kB (U) 0*1024kB 1*2048kB (U) 0*4096kB = 71036kB
[661080.310415] Node 0 hugepages_total=0 hugepages_free=0 hugepages_surp=0 hugepages_size=1048576kB
[661080.310417] Node 0 hugepages_total=0 hugepages_free=0 hugepages_surp=0 hugepages_size=2048kB
[661080.310419] 23112 total pagecache pages
[661080.310421] 9526 pages in swap cache
[661080.310422] Free swap  = 124kB
[661080.310423] Total swap = 4194300kB
[661080.310425] 3656454 pages RAM
[661080.310426] 0 pages HighMem/MovableOnly
[661080.310428] 94246 pages reserved
[661080.310429] 0 pages hwpoisoned
[661080.310430] Tasks state (memory values in pages):
[661080.310431] [  pid  ]   uid  tgid total_vm      rss rss_anon rss_file rss_shmem pgtables_bytes swapents oom_score_adj name
[661080.310444] [    407]     0   407    14785      160      160        0         0   135168      192          -250 systemd-journal
[661080.310449] [    444]     0   444     7633      247      247        0         0    81920      465         -1000 systemd-udevd
[661080.310455] [   1070]   990  1070     4424       64       64        0         0    77824      160          -900 systemd-oomd
[661080.310460] [   1073]   991  1073     6017      320      320        0         0    81920      378             0 systemd-resolve
[...]

I also see lines like:
[697936.532263] amdgpu 0000:0a:00.0: [drm] pstate TEST_DEBUG_DATA: 0x3FFD0000

Is it possible to diagnose what is going wrong?

How much RAM do you have?

Possible memory leak. With nothing running try running command 'free'  (shows memory usage) every minute and see if the number increases. If it ok then observer memory use when it it failing. If its really high and increasing suspect a rough app. Of course any app. could cause this but start with the basic system and then test with suspected apps. I had this trouble with a clean 24.04 install with a common /home. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1515740/swap-memory-really-leak-on-freshish-install-of-24-04
