Ubuntu desktop gets corrupted?
Since my upgrade to Ubuntu 24.04.1 my desktop gets in an unusable state every now and then, in particular after screen lock.

The Dock is absent
Desktop icons are absent
Top left, I see an orange square with a white 1
Sometimes, the Settings options to show the Dock or Desktop icons are absent
Sometimes, the icon on the left in the menubar which is supposed to show me all windows, gives me a black nonresponsive screen, from where I can only logout/shutdown.
The Just Perfection extension which moves my clock to the right seems to 'forget' its settings

What is going on here?

That might indicate some sort of memory leak. (Also no swap or not enough memory.) Try a fresh boot followed my running 'free' every minute or so and see if it is creeping up. I had something similar caused my desktop icons. Take a look at the following link for details: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1515740/swap-memory-really-leak-on-freshish-install-of-24-04

I believe the symptoms are too specific for a memory leak.

The problems are solved if I disable all Gnome extensions, it is probably the Dash to Dock extension that is the culprit here.

Yes, that does does sound similar to my problem (see link in comments in question) If you look at the answer it will tell you how to disable each gnome extension in turn to find the culprit. I think I had two uncooperative icons. You could add your name to the bug if it is sufficiently similar. (See link for bug number.)

There is something seriously wrong about the gnome extension system. Disabling all extensions at once solves the problem, while disabling them one by one does not. Looks like it's time for a new window manager.
