Desktop Icons gone in Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS
Upgrading to latest version removed the Desktop Icon Ding. It is enabled in extension manager but extension manager but desktop icons not showing up.

Welcome to ASK. This happened to me and it turned out to be problems with the gome-extension ding. It came with an additional memory leak  See the following link for details: - https://askubuntu.com/questions/1515740/swap-memory-really-leak-on-freshish-install-of-24-04
